# Custom Template Controls: .ascx or vbhtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, ascx

Does anyone have any recommendations about using a .ascx file (user control) versus a .vbhtml/.cshtml (razor) for custom templates?  It would appear from my limited interaction that they are completely interchangeable.

Is it purely a matter of comfort/experience or are there pros and cons to each method?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are interchangeable. But if your main application uses Razor I would recommend you using Razor for those templates. Unless you have some legacy code from some older ASP.NET MVC 2 application that you want to reuse. For all new views I recommend Razor.

Comment: It does, so that's what I'll do (and also what I was hoping to hear).  Thanks Darin!

Comment: Razor is 100% the way to go. The syntax is wayyy better